# Why content overflows in a div even after specifying widths

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to display two divs(`header-logo` and `nav-menu`) in a div. One floats to right and other to left.

Each div is of fixed width(100px). 
The second div is moving outside the `head-banner`. I'm not able to figure out why the content overflows the`head-banner`.

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
         <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <style>
        
      .head-banner{
       background: cyan;
       //overflow:hidden;
      }
      .header-logo{
       width: 100px;
           background:yellow;
float:left;
      }
      .nav-menu{
        background:green;
       width:100px;
       float:right;
      }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div class='head-banner'>
       <div class='header-logo'>
        div1
       </div>
       <div class='nav-menu'> 
        div2
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

**EDIT**

I can't see the color of .head-banner. I think both header-logo, nav-menu are pushed out.

If I make `overflow` of `head-banner` to be hidden, It's working as expected.

I want to know why it is so.

Comment: why did you cleared `float` before navigation?

Comment: _"One floats to right and other to left"_ - not really. You have one floated to the right, but the first one you left in normal flow.

Comment: Edited the code. Now it's correct

Comment: It's working, what are you questioning?

Comment: I can't see the color of .head-banner. I think both header-logo, nav-menu are pushed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer on google.

> If a div has all the elements floating then the div will collapse
>   itself

Answer (score 1):

you missed float:left for logo.

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
         <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <style>
        
      .head-banner{
       background: cyan;
       overflow:hidden;
      }
      .header-logo{
       width: 100px;
       background:yellow;
float:left;
      }
      .nav-menu{
        background:green;
       width:100px;
       float:right;
      }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div class='head-banner'>
       <div class='header-logo'>
        div1
       </div>
       <div class='nav-menu'> 
        div2
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep one div `float:left` and another one `float:right`

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
         <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <style>
        
      .head-banner{
       background: cyan;
       overflow:hidden;
      }
      .header-logo{
       width: 100px;
       background:yellow;
                float:left; 
      }
      .nav-menu{
        background:green;
       float:right;
      }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div class='head-banner'>
       <div class='header-logo'>
        div1
       </div>
       <div class='nav-menu'> 
        div2
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you need to define left for one div and right for another it will work ..

Answer (score 0):

**Change Like This:**

```
.head-banner{
    background: cyan;
    overflow: hidden;<-------Added
}

.header-logo{
    width: 100px;
    background:yellow;
    float: left;<---------Added
}

.nav-menu{
    background:green;
    width:100px;
    float:right;
}
```

```css
.head-banner{
    background: cyan;
    overflow: hidden;<-------Added
}

.header-logo{
    width: 100px;
    background:yellow;
    float: left;<---------Added
}

.nav-menu{
    background:green;
    width:100px;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class='head-banner'>
    <div class='header-logo'>
       div1
    </div>
    <div class='nav-menu'> 
       div2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first div is still `display: block` which is causing the 2nd div to be shown on the next line. You can fix this a couple ways:

1. set the first div to `float: left`
2. set the first div to `display: inline-block`

My personal preference is #2, so that's what I did in the below snippet.

```css
.head-banner{
  background: cyan;
}
.head-banner div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.header-logo{
  width: 100px;
  background:yellow;
}
.nav-menu{
  background:green;
  width:100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='head-banner'>
  <div class='header-logo'>
    div1
  </div>
  <div class='nav-menu'> 
    div2
  </div>
</div>
```